# Angular Material Flex: positioning a FAB dial relative to a responsive image

Tags: css, angularjs, css-position, flexbox, angular-material

> Plunker available [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/x9UvdT5c9MnonSM4IJFB?p=preview)

We have a responsive grid-list of md-cards. I want to position the FAB always at the same place in the card, but it's responsive, so the cards size change, and I don't really have an idea on how to position it correctly.

I want to achieve something similar to this, but in all the responsive sizes:

[image]

I've tried with `position: absolute`, `position:relative`, and translates, and didn't achieve much, but my css skills are far from being great.

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: FYI, the "flex" tag refers to Apache Flex (think Flash programming) -- as the tag wiki says, use "flexbox" instead for CSS questions.

Comment: Didn't know, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try like this:

```
<div class="background-profile" style="position:relative; background-image:url('http://www.pisobarcelona.com/Mantenimiento/Fotos/Foto9432Piso2292.jpg')">
  <md-card-title>
     <md-card-title-text>
        <span class="md-headline">300€ por mes</span>
     </md-card-title-text>
  </md-card-title>
      <md-fab-speed-dial md-open="false" ng-class="md-fling" style="position:absolute; bottom:0; right:0; transform: translate(0%, 0%);">
        <md-fab-trigger>
            <md-button aria-label="menu" class="md-fab md-warn">
             <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/menu.svg"></md-icon>
            </md-button>
       </md-fab-trigger>
     </md-fab-speed-dial>

</div>
```

Comment: With right: -30px it seems to do the trick! Thanks! I'll just wait a bit to see if there's a more "flex-like" approach before validating the answer.